# or condition and for loop bad used?

Tags: python

I've a problem setting a double if condition in a for loop.

Supposing to have a list of lists that I've appended during my previous code:

```
...
...
lines=[[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
```

I want to evaluate inside a for loop when 2 or 0 are in lines[k], if one of them are in lines[k], the code have to pass and do next code, if they are not in lines[k] it will continue the for loop. I've coded it like this:

```
for k in range(0,4):
    if 2 not in list[k] or 0 not in list[k]:
        continue
    else:
        pass
    do other analysis
```

In my head this code have to work like this:

```
for k=0 ---> lines[0]=[1,1,1] must continue and go to k=1
for k=1 ---> lines[1]=[1,2,1] must pass and do other analysis (2 is in liens)
for k=2 ---> lines[2]=[1,0,1] must pass and do other analysis (0 is in lines)
for k=3 ---> lines[3]=[1,1,1] must continue and finish.
```

Anyway it is not working... It might be the 'or' command used in the wrong way ?

How can I fix my code ? Any idea ?

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: the test is `in` or `not in`; not `is in` or `is not in`.

Comment: Also you don't need the `else`, since if the condition is met il will restart the loop anyway.

Comment: Your code uses `list`, not `lines`, as the name of the list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if one of them are in lines[k], the code have to pass and do next code

The If statement should be：

```
if 2 in list[k] or 0 in list[k]:
    pass
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Classic De Morgan's law. Stumps the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

You are complicating stuff by combining `or` and `not`. Your code will actually do the opposite of what you expect.

Here's a short way of doing it using a simple generator expression.

```
>>> lines = [[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
>>> for line in (L for L in lines if 0 in L or 2 in L):
...     print(line)
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
```

In some cases it might be clearer if you use grouping parentheses when you combine boolean expressions (`and`, `or`, `not`).

The following code is is similar to your original, but the grouping parentheses makes it easier to reason about the expression.

```
>>> for line in lines:
...    if not ((0 in line) or (2 in line)):
...        continue
...    print(line)
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
```

You can also use the builtin `filter()` function to do this. In my eyes, this is the most readable solution. Readability is key to avoiding these kinds of bugs. Writing that extra function also makes it very easy to test and debug.

```
>>> def contains_0_or_2(line):
...     return (0 in line) or (2 in line)

>>> for line in filter(contains_0_or_2, lines):
...     print(line)
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `list[k]` but `list` is a built-in object in Python. You want to use `lines[k]` because you gave your list the name `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to check each nested list inside `lines = [[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]` whether it contains `2` or `0` and perform a certain operation if that is the case.

You can do this by looping over the nested lists inside `lines`:

```
lines = [[1,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]

for sublist in lines:
    if 2 in sublist or 0 in sublist:
        # Perform operation, e. g. 
        print('Performing operation on ' + str(sublist))
```

As already stated, the syntax for checking if an iterable contains a certain value is `in` or `not in`, not `is in` or `is not in` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to test for membership

```
test = set([0, 2])

for thing in lines:
    if test.isdisjoint(thing):
        continue
    print(thing)
```

or

```
for thing in lines:
    if not test.intersection(thing):
        continue
    print(thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking if the array does not contain any 0 OR if it does not contain any 2.

An array like this: [1,2,1] fulfills the condition, since although it does contain a 2, it does not contain any 0. You should write `and` instead of `or`, but there is a better solution:

```
if 2 in lines[k] or 0 in lines[k]:
    # do other analysis
```

This is shorter, and also more efficient.